# UITableView separator appear in middle of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Sometimes my tableviewcell separator appear in middle of cell. I searched and found one solution that I can set SeparatorStyle as none and set my custom separator at bottom of cell, but I don't want to do that.

I want to know root cause that why it appear only sometimes. Are there any other solutions than this? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585378/uitableview-separator-appears-in-middle-of-cells-view/) as well, but no help. Screenshot attached:

[image]

### Edit

I have searched the web and tried all available solution, but it's not working.

Tried this below code as well:

```
upNextTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
upNextTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Comment: Can you show us your relevant code?

Comment: And a screenshot please!

Comment: Have you tried tableView.rowHeight = UITableVIew.automaticDimension and tableView.estimatedRowHeight = SomeValue for cell height?

Comment: @RatneshJain I have tried that as well, issue still there

Comment: I have searched on google and tried all available solution, its not working thats why posted question. If you don't know solution, please don't downvote without any reason.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you use autolayout and have implemented the heightForRowAt delegate method and that method returns a value that doesn't match the actual height of the cell.

Comment: I have not added heightForRowAt method

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

add these two lines of code to your table view controller's viewDidLoad() method:

```
tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Now look for you cellForRowAt method and add this:

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Answer (score 0):

The separator cannot appear in the middle of the cell, this is just impossible.

But there is a chance the content from your cell is bigger than the cell itself, and it overlaps the next cell.

Make sure you have set all the constrains correctly.
If the cell should have dynamic height, make sure to specify it in the tableView. [here is a useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443494/some-tableview-cells-with-dynamic-height-other-with-fixed-height)
Or just set the clipToBounds = true, to the cell...

Comment: I have all constrains correctly. clipToBounds is true

Comment: clipToBounds of the actual UITableViewCell?
For debugging try to set some BG color for the actual cell, to see if the content is pushed...

Comment: yes, I tried added background color, separator is actually shifting up

Comment: can you show me a screenshot of the UITableViewCell in storyboard with all view hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Select the Table View and go to the Attributes Inspector.

See below:

[image]

Next, go to the Separator Inset and change it from Automatic to Custom.

Answer (score 0):

this can be happened if you `override setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` in your `customCell`, and if you call `layoutIfNeeded(`) in the *setSelected function*.

`layoutIfNeeded()` will lay out the subviews immediately, so the separator line will be drawn while `layoutIfNeeded()` is working!